# Running HTML without CSS in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

So I installed Visual Studio Code to build my website, I wrote my code using HTML and CSS and when I try to run it It gives me "localhost refused to connect." knowing that I downloaded Live Server.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <div class="hero">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you have installed the live server extension and clicked go live in the status bar at the bottom?

Comment: What Exactly Extension do you installed?

Comment: I downloaded Live Server from Ritwick Dey

Comment: You clicked the **Go live** button at the bottom in your html file? and also Live server do not opens in localhost